# Free styled SQL request on CoreData

Tags: core-data

I have tow tables where User (id,name) and UserInfo (user_id,email,date_edit)

How i can do SQL request to CoreData like

```
select * from user inner join userinfo on userinfo.user_id=user.id
```

Without using relationships bu CoreData?

Another example:

I want fetch max date_edit from userinfo table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of thinking in SQL and trying to translate that to Core Data, start with the problem you are trying to solve. Then, express that using Core Data relationships.

For example, if you wanted to get an array of emails for an array of users, you could just do something like:

```
NSArray *emailArray = [usersArray valueForKeyPath:@"userInfo.email"];
```

Core Data has aggregate functions. You might be able to do something simple with KVO like:

```
NSNumber *maxDateEdit = [userInfoArray valueForKeyPath:@"@max.date_edit"];
```

Otherwise, check out the section "Fetching Objects" [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FetchingObjects.html)